# How to adjust height and width of TextView according to EditText properties?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I am creating a image editor. To write a text over image, we would like to have text autoresize feature. 
For the same I would like to calculate height of editText based on

1. Characters
2. Width of editText
3. font-size

I think it will also vary with font-family and font-weight, if so how to consider all these while calculating height of editText.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds

Comment: applies only for Android 8+ ?

Comment: @quicklearner I saw that answer ..My need is slightly differert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set up your `editText` with font needed, then call:

```
Rect bounds = new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
String textToMeasure = "SOME TEXT"; 
Paint textPaint = editText.getPaint();
textPaint.getTextBounds(textToMeasure, 0, textToMeasure.length(), bounds);
```

then you will get required width and height from `bounds`.

Comment: Thanks seems fine.. will try

Comment: can I get textSize  ..by setting bounds ? What textsize will fit a bound given font-family and text

Comment: I don't think so, yo can try different text sizes and check bounds